# LocalStorage inside a service doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, local-storage, angular-services, angular-local-storage

I have a code that works perfectly inside a controller but after moving it to service, it seems to not work and crush right after this:

```
return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("SavedContacts"));
```

the service code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ["ngStorage"]);
app.service('ContactManager', function()
{
    this.Contacts={};
    this.GetJsonFile = function ()
    {
        return JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("SavedContacts"));
    }
    this.Contacts = this.GetJsonFile();
    ...
}
```

Thanks for any help.

EDIT:

A sample : http://plnkr.co/edit/jjInJp4lJcC1oCvXZ1oN?p=preview

Comment: Are you getting an error in console? Can you add a jsfiddle/plunkr?

Comment: Define "not work and crush". What happens precisely?

Comment: Your plunkr works just fine. You still haven't told what you meant by "not work and crush", but my guess is that you have something in your local storage that is not valid JSON and thus can't be parsed. Use your browser dev tools to remove it.

Comment: Thanks that was the answer! Idk how a not valid json came there but anyway write it as one and we close it :) Thanks again!